# Haskell abstract datatypes and retrieving characters/defining as strings

Tags: haskell

I had a datatype, example:

```
data MyData = Something1 String
```

and then I had a function

```
myFunction :: MyData -> String
myFunction x = x
```

within myFunction I want to refer to the characters ie ['S','o','m','e'......'1'] which are in my data type MyData. However, I get the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
>                   with actual type`MyData'
>       Expected type: String
>         Actual type: MyData

As far as I understand [Char] is the same as String, and I have declared 'Something1' as String, so it should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Char]` is the same as `String`, but neither is the same as `MyData`. To access the string stored within your data type, you'll need to use pattern matching:

```
myFunction :: MyData -> String
myFunction (Something1 xs) = xs
```

This is because the `data` keyword makes a completely new data type. If you only wanted an alias, you could also use the `type` keyword:

```
type MyData = String

myFunction :: MyData -> String
myFunction x = x
```

Comment: I should just tell you my overall problem, i want to create custom data types, but I need to be able to access the characters composing them (like Something1) in my code.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're trying to do. No, you cannot access the name of the constructor itself directly, although you can define a function `myFunction (Something1 _) = "Something1"`. A more advanced option is to derive the `Data` and `Typeable` type classes. This will allow you to write `myFunction x = showConstr (toConstr x)`, but it's the same thing under the hood, with the compiler creating the boilerplate for you.

Answer (score 2):

MyData is *not* the same as String. It is just very similar.

You can declare a type synonym like this:

```
type MyData = String
```

and then MyData and String are two names for the same type. In fact, String is already a type synonym of [Char]. In this case, `myFunction` is just the identity function `id`.

Or you can use pattern matching to extract the String from a MyData like this:

```
myFunction :: MyData -> String
myFunction (Something1 xs) = xs
```

Alternatively, you can use the record syntax to make the accessor automatically:

```
data MyData = Something1 { myFunction :: String}
```

(this is practically identical to declaring `myFunction` as above, except you can now construct `MyData`s  using the syntax `Something1 { myFunction = x }` as well as `Something1 x`)

Comment: Hi Max, if i were to use type MyData = String, could I then declare which abstract types could be part of MyData using constructors? I want to declare MyData only allowed say Object1 | Object2 | Object3 and then being able to access those Objectx's, to retrieve their characters?

Comment: No. If you use type MyData = String, then MyData and String are exactly the same. I'm not sure what you mean by "retrieving Objectx's characters" though.